# Schema error at paths should NOT have additional properties in SWAGGER

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0

Please help me to solve this issue

```
paths:   'sepa/sct/{OriginatorAccount}':
    post:
      tags:
        - SCT Initiation
      summary: SCT Initiation
      description: ''
      operationId: doSEPASCTInit
      parameters:
        - name: OriginatorAccount
          in: path
          description: Originator Account
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          description: Input Content
          name: body
          required: false
          schema:
              $ref: '#/definitions/MandateInfo'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MandateInfo'
        '400':
          description: Operation failed
        default:
          description: Alert details added successfully.
```

**Error:**

> Schema error at paths should NOT have additional properties
>   additionalProperty: sepa/sct/{OriginatorAccount}

Comment: it's swagger 2.0

Comment: Got the issue; it's in path itself.. 

paths:   '/sepa/sct/{OriginatorAccount}':

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoint paths must begin with a forward slash `/`:

```
/sepa/sct/{OriginatorAccount}
```